# Sending Ctrl+C to a process

Tags: java, process

I have a [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object, which i need to terminate at a given point in time. 
I tried Process.destroy(), but this does not effectively let the process to release the port it was using, due to which i cannot use it. 
All i need to do is to send a "Ctrl + C" to the 'Process' which already has a shutdown hook written in it, which takes care of releasing any resources.

How can i do this.

I am Using Windows

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: Shutdown hooks are not always called on abnormal program termination (depends on the underlying OS).

Comment: I am also facing the same Issue and I have explained in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942679/how-to-terminate-a-process-normally-created-using-processbuilder

Can you please guide me that how this can be solved ? Any link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting on shutdown hooks for regular operation is a broken approach. You must design your application to provide its own protocol by which it can receive a shutdown signal. This is the only way to write a solid multiplatform application, where by "multiplatform" I also imply different versions of the same platform.

Comment: +1 you have to write your protocol with the assumption a connection to a service could die at any point. e.g. the power might fail.  You should try to give your protocol a graceful disconnect, but you cannot assume it will always be used.

Comment: I am also facing the same Issue and I have explained in detail here: stackoverflow.com/questions/27942679/… Can you please guide me that how this can be solved ? Any link ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a command using taskkill like explained in this [article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/446/xp_kill_windows_process_command_line_taskkill/).