# How to Terminate a Process Normally Created using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, windows, ffmpeg, processbuilder, kill-process

I am creating Processes using ProcessBuilder in my Java Application. The created process executes some FFMPEG commands which actually copy the RTSP streams in specified destination media file.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-i", RTSP_URL, "-f", fileFormat, destFilePath);
Process processToExecute = builder.start();
```

I want to close the process before it completes its execution. So, If I run this FFMPEG command directly in windows CMD and then press 'CTRL+C' after 5 seconds then process get terminates with status '2'. And I can play the media file created so far.

So, If I do the same operation in my Java Application using:

```
 process.destroy(); //I call this method after 5 sec
```

I get the status code '1' which means abnormal termination. I get the status by the following way:

```
 processToExecute.destroy();
 processToExecute.exitValue(); //This return me status '1'
```

And I can't play the media file and I think this is due to the abnormal termination of the process.

So how I can terminate the process created using ProcessBuilder in the same way we do in CMD with (CTRL+C) so that I may play the created media file ?

I want to terminate process (created using ProcessBuilder) in Java Application with status code of '2' that I get when I terminate process using CMD.

## EDIT#01: --- Sharing Findings

So, when I try to delete that file once app terminates, I get the following error:

```
The Action Can't be Performed Because File is Opened in FFMPEG.exe
```

Which means that process is not terminating the command it is executing. That command still has occupied this file that's why I am not getting able to play it. Process gets terminate when I call:

```
 processToExecute.destroy();
```

But, the task it is performing (that is execution of a command) is still active. Strange!!!!

## EDIT#02: Sharing Ultimate Reason

Actually If I directly press 'CTRL+C' or 'q' in cmd when process is running then it terminates the process successfully and this process is no more visible in the currently executing processes lists.

And Programatically when I call method:

```
cmd> processToExecute.destroy();
```

It terminates the process but when I see the list of currently executing processes I can still see them over there.

And same scenario exists If I try to terminate this process using 'taskkill' or 'kill' command in another CMD by specifying their's name or pid that still process terminates abnormally.

P.S. I use the following command to see the running processes:

```
tasklist
```

So from this it proves that destroy() method from Application and 'taskkill or kill' command from another CMD is not terminating the process normally that pressing 'CTRL+C' and 'q' does.

Comment: I don't know if you can do this in Java, but based on your description, you need to send a control-C signal to FFMPEG.  The Win32 API call to do this is [GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Incidentally, the problem isn't the status code per se, that's just another symptom; terminating the process with status code 2 is no different to terminating it with status code 1.  You have to *ask* it to terminate (rather than forcing it to do so) so that it can run its cleanup routines.

Comment: If it's ffmpeg, maybe send it a 'q' key to tell it to quit...

Comment: yes If I send 'q' through cmd it does terminate process normally. But I want to terminate it from inside my Application.

Comment: @BilalAhmedYaseen: Did you get a solution to this? I am getting the same issue.

Comment: I created a library do do video exporting (https://github.com/hamoid/video_export_processing) and run into this exact issue on Windows. Would it be possible to send keystrokes to the process, as proposed at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240704/execute-external-program-using-processbuilder-and-provide-input ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to terminate all child in your procees with something like :

```
process.children().forEach(processHandle -> processHandle.destroy());
process.destroy();
```

Answer (score -4):

Maybe try...

```
builder.inheritIO();
System.exit(2);
```

Or you could try to write to the stdin of the process...

```
process.getInputStream().write(exitCode);
```

Comment: There is no such 'inheritIO()' method for 'Process' class in Java.

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process processToExecute = builder.start();

Comment: Dear Again there is no 'write()' method on InputStream. We can just read from InputStream while we can Write on OutputStream. And with OutputStream It makes no sense.

Comment: He misprinted, he ment `process.getOutputStream().write(exitCode)`. Because `getInputStream()` returns readonly stream connected to the STDOUT of the subprocess. While `getOutputStream()` returns stream that is connected to the STDIN of the subprocess.